# Does a doppelganger who's replaced a PC get their stats for rolls?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

I'm running a mini campaign within a normal campaign, which has a different DM. The regular DM has a PC of their own and we, as a group, thought it would be fun to let the DM really play their character and give someone else a chance to DM for a bit. So when I took over as temporary DM, I removed my PC (through shenanigans) so I could concentrate on DMing as its my first time.

However, I thought it would be fun to bring back my PC except as a doppelganger pretending to be them. I'd obviously make them act different, and the doppelganger would be trying to lead the party into danger and whatnot. But does the doppelganger get to use my normal PC's stats for rolls? We all have access to each other's sheets because its an online game so I think they would notice if I was using different stats/modifiers. But I don't want to do off-site rolls for the doppelganger!PC in case they get suspicious right away.

We're playing a D&D based homebrew game FYI.

Answer (score 5):

## A Doppelganger is its own creature, and such has its own statblock.

So it would definately not use your stats. It would also not be able to do all the things you do. It just *looks* like you, but unless the original Doppelganger had magical powers, it can't do the spells you do, it probably doesn't have the attacks you have, and unless it's exceptionally wealthy or has access to your corpse, it also doesn't have the gear you have.

This is of course also much fairer - it's impossible for the players to notice that "your
character" is actually something else if it has to struggle to keep up the charade. Ultimately, the Doppelganger is an imposter, not an evil clone.

In addition, by default a Doppelganger is a *monster*, which means it has a monster's statblock, far fewer active abilities and power, more HP, etc.

In 4e, there is a strict divide between the players and their characters and the NPCs. The Doppelganger is on the NPC side of things.

If you want to have a DM-controlled NPC who adventurers with the party and has a statblock like a regular player-character, you'll have to create it using the rules for a player character. While there are rules for creating a Doppelganger player character in the Monster Manual, consider creating a **changeling** (from the Eberron campaign setting), they can also look like others but are specifically designed to be PCs. As such, they have much more story detail as well as specific racial feats and other mechanics available. (It would still be pretty weird to have one that has the same class and same powers as the PC, though. Remember: imposter, not evil clone)